# Utidev webserver's windows service not running

Tags: cassini

im trying to host my website developed in ASP.net4.0 in Ultidev's casini webserver 2.0.

bt when i try to host the same or click on http::/localhost:port, im getting following error.

Utidev webserver's windows service not running.

I dont hav clue on the windows service it's expecting.
Do i need to install any other dependencies ?[image]
Please look at the error pic.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The host process for that application, DefaultSharedHostProcess, is having trouble starting. Look in the Windows Event Log, as well as "UWS.Installer.log.txt", "RegRepairTrace.txt" and "AppRegTrace.txt" files in the "%ProgramFiles%\UltiDev\Web Server" folder.

As there are a variety of circumstances which can lead to this error, you will need to edit your question and add in the relevant error details you discover from the logs, or go start a thread on UltiDev's support forum. For instance, I encountered this error because of a permissions issue to machine.config in a .NET 4 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today, and found if I recycle the host process, I was up and running.

In the UltiDev Web Server Explorer window on the left side, click on the Default Shared Host Process.
On the right side, you'll see a button named "Recycle Host Process". Click it, and answer Yes.

After this, the Windows Service started up, and I was able to communicate with my web app.

[image]

Comment: As an add-on answer, the other possibility is that the PC only has .NET 4.0 Client Profile installed, not the full 4.0 Framework.  I found that this was the reason my installer failed to automatically configure my UltiDev ASP.NET service.